# Goldwing motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle

2013 honda Goldwing motorcycle what antifreeze is compatible with this motorcycle?  I have flushed antifreeze wanting to replace antifreeze?

Answer (score 3):

Honda calls for their brand of anti-freeze but it's the standard (often "green" but color may vary across manufacturer) ethylene glycol-based stuff.

Personally, however, I like EngineICE or similar "safe" propylene-glycol-based coolants since they are not poisonous.  I know EngineICE meets all the same specifications that ethylene gloycol-based coolants do.  If your bike is still covered under Honda warranty, however, you will probably want to use exactly what is called for in the manual just to avoid any possibility of being denied a claim in the future.

The Honda Owners Manual is available online here:

[GL1800 Owners Manual](https://cdn.powersports.honda.com/documentum/MWOM/ml.remawmom.2013_31mjk6000_gl1800_a.pdf)

To quote them:

> Use Pro Honda HP coolant or an equivalent high quality ethylene glycol
>   antifreeze containing corrosion protection inhibitors specifically
>   recommended for use in aluminum engines. Check the antifreeze
>   container label.
>
> Use only distilled water as a part of the coolant
>   solution. Water that is high in mineral content or salt may be harmful
>   to the aluminum engine.
>
> The factory provides a 50/50 solution of
>   antifreeze and water in this motorcycle. This coolant solution is
>   recommended for most operating temperatures and provides good
>   corrosion protection.

Do NOT under any circumstances use any coolant marked "Dex" or "Dex-Cool" as this is a very different formulation and is not suitable for Honda GL1800s.